# VB net how to call dynamic textbox from other button

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to change the text of my dynamic textbox using a button  but I'm getting a

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Here is how I created my dynamic textbox

```
    Dim txt1 As New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Controls.Add(txt1)
    txt1.Name = "TextBox"
    txt1.Text = "0"
```

And here is what the code inside my button

```
   Dim myTB As New TextBox
    myTB = Me.Controls("TextBox")
    myTB.Text = "2"
```

Can anyone here give me some advice I'm not familiar in dynamic controls

Comment: You need to [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=net-5.0) your control - try `Me.Controls.Find("TextBox", true)`

Comment: its displaying "Value of type 'Control()' cannot be converted to 'Textbox"

Comment: Ah, right - you need to cast the found `Control` to `TextBox` ... try `myTB = TryCast(Me.FindControl("TextBox"), TextBox)`

Comment: it showing 'FindControl' is not a member of Form1 i try 
myTB = TryCast(Me.Controls.Find("TextBox"), TextBox)
but it showing error

Comment: Dim myTB As New TextBox
        myTB = TryCast(Me.FindControl("TextBox"), TextBox)
        myTB.Text = "2"
this one is showing 'FindControl' is not a member of Form1

Comment: it work
   Dim myTB As New TextBox
        myTB = TryCast(Me.Controls("TextBox"), TextBox)
        myTB.Text = "2" i use this
thank you so much